# Space above and below banner image

Tags: image, padding, space

There is some white space above and below the banner image.
Here's the page: http://www.epsilon144.com

Does anybody know what I can do to remove the space so the banner connects with the navigation bar underneath it?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: show your code which you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the css of image inside the banner `div` to:

```
display:block
```